# Pyomo Mixed Integer Linear Optimization Code to multiple set of variables with binary variables and prices

Tags: optimization, pyomo, mixed-integer-programming

Helly everyone,

I am a new user to pyomo and have some problem at the moment.

I am trying to develop a multi-time period mixed-integer optimization problem in python with pyomo. I have 4 technologies for which I want to optimize the capacity over 12 periods (1-12). If technology 1 gets chosen in a period technology 2 is not chosen in that period. The same goes for technologies 3 and 4. Each of these technologies has its own price per period. I set up a list for all the variables for each technologies in each period(x11-x124), for the binary variable of each technology in each period and for the price of each technology in each period. However, I am unable to write a working objective function for all these variables.

I would appreciate any help!

Below is the image of the code I have tried. I have also tried. I however get the error: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.

I have also tried first transforming the lists into numpy.arrays. I however then get an error because I cannot use numpy in a pyomo optimization

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQinz.png)

Comment: I would use the same indexing scheme for all three symbols (capacity, price_index, binary). Now they all use something different ('x11'...;  0,1,...; 'b11'...).

Comment: @EnergyHydrogenCoder – Post code as text.

Comment: What you have described is not a “starter problem.”  I would encourage you to do some practice with smaller problems and properly set up some sets, parameters and variables.